# Do 3Ds Max and other 3D programs use the dedicated graphic card by default, if not specified?

Tags: graphics-card, nvidia-graphics-card, 3d-modeling, 3d-graphics, 3ds-max

I have the following graphic cards installed on my laptop:

- Intel (R) HD Graphics 4000
- NVIDIA GeForce GTX 675M 2,0 GB GDDR5 dedicated

I installed a 3D modelling software (3Ds Max); on the preference settings window I cannot find where graphic card settings are, so I wonder if ->

- Is 3Ds Max using my NVIDIA dedicated card or the graphic processor?
- More generally do 3D modelling softwares use the dedicated graphic card or the graphic processor by default, if nothing is specified in the software settings?

Comment: From what you describe, you have nVidia Optimus technology in your laptop.  Both of those chips are dedicated graphics processors, but the laptop switches between the two depending on the work load (Intel for light, nVidia for heavy).  Unfortunately, I don't have an exact method on how to figure out when the laptop switches.

Comment: 3D Max can be configure to use any GPU it supports.  Check the 3D Max support articles on how to do this.